# Dynamically Loaded content's CSS and links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm saving data using cKEditor from backend.
I click on item and it is loaded dynamically in a div.
The issue is that I am not able to use links and css elements like `<h1>` and `<strong>` are not working.

Here's the code to get data:

```
var catid = $(this).attr("data-id"); //Get Category ID
        var apdata='';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getChildren',
            data: {id: catid},
            type:'get',
            //cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                apdata = '';
                console.log(data);
                if(data['success']) {
                    $('.rcontainer').empty();
                    $(data.records).each(function(i,item){
                        apdata += '<div class="set"><a href="#">' + item.title +'<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a><div class="content acdcontent">' + item.content + '<p class="UIFaq_Sharing"><a class="permalinknavigate" data-link="help/'+ item.slug +'" target="_blank" href="#">Permalink</a><span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"> · </span></p><p class="UIFaq_Sharing vote">Was this answer helpful? <span class="ansbuttons"><a class="vote" data-vote="yes" data-id="'+ item.blogID +'" href="#">Yes</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="vote" data-vote="no" data-id="'+ item.blogID +'" href="#">No</a></span></p></div></div>';
                    });
                    $('.rcontainer').append(apdata);
                    $('.rcontainer').show();

                    voting();
                    permalink();
                } else {
                    alert('No data found');
                }
                accord();
                $(".accordion-container .content").css("max-height","150px");
                $(".accordion-container .content").css("overflow","auto");
            }
        });
```

Neither href is working nor `<strong>` items are shown in bold. Any solution? Please help

Comment: links don't work in contentEditable sections...

Comment: How to solve this issue? What's meant by contentEditable section?

Comment: That is an easy google search, however I don't see how it applies to this question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: It's irrelevant to this question.